# Binary names for the Type Variables - in classes/interfaces/method/constructor

Tags: java, jls, binary-compatibility, type-variables

Consider the following clause from the **JLS §13.1**

> - The **binary name** of a **type variable** declared by a **generic class or interface** (§8.1.2, §9.1.2) is the binary name of its immediately enclosing type, followed by $, followed by the simple name of the type variable.
> - The **binary name** of a **type variable** declared by a **generic method** (§8.4.4) is the binary name of the type declaring the method, followed by $, followed by the descriptor of the method as defined in The Java Virtual Machine Specification, Java SE 7 Edition, followed by $, followed by the simple name of the type variable.
> - The **binary name** of a **type variable** declared by a **generic constructor** (§8.8.4) is the binary name of the type declaring the constructor, followed by $, followed by the descriptor of the constructor as defined in The Java Virtual Machine Specification, Java SE 7 Edition, followed by $, followed by the simple name of the type variable.

Following are my doubts:

1. **Why is binary naming conventions dictated for the Type Variables declared in the Class/Interface/Methods/Constructors?**

   - Ideally this should't have been - as they are always referred to wrt the class of which they are members of.
   - Also Binary names are used to refer to the class/Interfaces that have an independent representation as a `.class` file - not for the Type Variables.
2. Any **example program which I can decompile to see if this is practically happening?**

   - eg when **decompiling the anonymous classes** - I can verify the naming conventions being declared to be true.
   - Not Not able to find any example - where Binary Name is getting generated for the Type Variable.

Comment: You have made two statements. What is your question exactly?

Comment: @Sweeper : my doubt is that the binary names for the type variables are not possible - because of above points I made - but JLS says it is possible. Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: @theutonium.18 Please [edit] your post to include a question you want to ask. Add a more detailed description of the problem you have with the binary names.

Comment: @Progman : Have rephrased my doubts.